# Fastest framework for image processing

Tags: objective-c, macos, image-processing

I am developing something like painting app. There will be ability to draw on large images. I already have implemented this ability. Now I need to add ability for image processing (effects like: blur, hue, saturation, brightness, contrast, sepia...). That would be OK to do it with `CoreImage` framework, but I met one problem. All my painting and image drawing is based on OpenGL. And when I try to process image (apply effect on it) with core image and send it back to OpenGL to draw to screen I have some performance issues like `slow image processing` when trying to do it in real time. User moves slider and with slider position changes image gets updated. So if image is pretty big (for example 3200x2000), this action becomes slow. If image is smaller (for example 1500x1000) it works beautifully. So I came up with conclusion that it's framework's problem. If i'm wrong tell me. So what framework could I use for fast image processing? I found `vImage`, but as I can see, it does not have ability to apply such effects. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you be hitting the maximum texture size for your GPU? Core Image falls back to CPU-bound processing for images above a certain size, because they can't be represented in a single texture. Some of the GPUs I've worked with on the desktop only go up to 2048x2048 for a max texture size.

Comment: How frequently are you updating the image? "User moves slider and with slider position changes image gets updated." Are you handling every notification of a changed value for the slider? (I work with .NET and Qt, so I'm not sure how slider value change notifications may be handled in your framework, or if they can be handled faster than the screen refresh rate). If you're not already doing so, consider using a timer to limit the rate at which the value changed notification is handled. Is there a user demand for handling changes at screen refresh rates? Would 10 fps be satisfactory?

Answer (score 0):

This could fit almost all of your requirements [GPUImage framework by Brad](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage)

Comment: But it is for iOS and I need for OS X